# Tel input doesn't fire event on return

Tags: android, forms, cordova, android-webview, dom-events

I'm developing a Phonegap application on Android & IOS.

I can't find a solution for the following case.

I have a single field form to get zipcode (4 char length in my country). To get the numeric keyboard without thousand separator I used the next hack:

```
<input type="tel" name="myName" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

My problem is that I'm unable to hide keyboard without tap outside the field (to blur). 
The "return" key isn't catchable (I can catch it with a text type but not with tel or number).

I know that forms fields (& related features) are really buggy on Android (as a lot of others stuffs in webviews).

Which hack could you suggest me to handle my problem?

Comment: Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209421/android-input-type-number-confirm-enter-button-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

In Android Use this line before setContentView(R.layout.main);
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Definitely you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Update]:

The workaround that work for me:

```
<input id="locator_zipcode" name="locator_zip" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" size="4" maxlength="4"
 onkeyup="
 if(isAndroid()){
     if($('#locator_zipcode').attr('value').length==4){
         setTimeout(function(){
             $('#locator_zipcode').blur();
         },500);
     }
 }"/>
```

Comment: [Converted OP's question edit to an answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)